# Swift send JSON data server via POST PHP server

Tags: php, json, swift, post

When I use Swift to give data via POST JSON to server I get fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I am not sure if it is way I am passing JSON library dictionary or is it problem when sending to server since I do not have access to see server PHP code.

I am not sure how the

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as! NSArray
```

works.

I create my JSON dictionary with

```
func parseExportDB() -> [AnyObject]{

    var exportDict: [AnyObject] = []

    for tuple in export {
        var dictObj = [
            "PhoneID": "petrjanata",
            "LocLabel": tuple[crosslocation],
            "Latitude": "123",
            "Longitude": "-123",
            "time" : tuple[time],
            "heading" : tuple[heading]
        ]
        exportDict.append(dictObj)
        println(dictObj)
    }

    return exportDict
}
```

I take `exportDict` JSON array object and pass into this function:

```
func sendJsonToServer(ExportList: AnyObject){

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://atonal.ucdavis.edu/geomus/submit_data.php")!)

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    if let serializedData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(ExportList, options: nil, error: &err){
        request.HTTPBody = serializedData
        println(request.HTTPBody)
    }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?

        let jsonString = self.JSONStringify(ExportList)
        println(jsonString)

        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as! NSArray
        // var json = noWrappedJson!
        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            for singleCode in json {
                if let parseJSON = singleCode as? NSDictionary {
                    // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                    var success = parseJSON["code"] as? String
                    println("Succes: \(success)")
                }
                else {
                    // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                }
            }
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}
```

The code enters fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as! NSArray
```

with error

I am not sure how to fix, or what exactly is wrong either JSON format or server?

Comment: plz dnt uz txtspk, itz rly unrdble & itz hrdly mch effrt 2 jst type prply. kthxbai!

Comment: sorry i from china not good english

Comment: I don't mean to criticise your English generally Teddy, we're fine with English that's not perfect. However "thx" and similar are probably best kept to Facebook `:-)`.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb for the future, before coming to StackOverflow with questions regarding sending and receiving data, it's best to verify that the issue is truly in your iOS application and not the API itself - this can be done with the Chrome app [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: You are doing a `println` of `strData`. Maybe you can show us what it looks like. Your `JSONObjectWithData` is trying to cast the result as an array. But is it really an array? Or perhaps a dictionary? Or perhaps some error message? You're telling us that `JSONObjectWithData` failed, but not showing us what the input looked like. Also, rather than `as! NSArray`, try `as? NSArray` and then see if `NSError` object has any information about why it failed (if the JSON parsing, itself failed).